# Warning and Fatal Error on Wordpress Website with Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, woocommerce

I am getting some weird errors on my wordpress website today even though I haven't installed/updated any plugin etc. So far I have tried disabling all the plugins, changing themes and even checked permission for wordpress folders and files.

Everything looks good. I have even updated PHP version for my website from 5.6 to 7.0 and increased the update file limit from 8MB to 16 MB as suggested on wordpress but nothing has worked. These are the following errors that I am getting.

On My-Admin Page

> careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-settings.php on line 425
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-settings.php on line 425

On Manage Themes Page in My Admin

> Warning:
>   include(/home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-settings.php on line 425
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-settings.php on line 425
>
> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with
>   WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have
>   problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not
>   establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your
>   server administrator.) in
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-includes/update.php on
>   line 499

On the home page of website

> Warning:
>   include(/home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-settings.php on line 425
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-settings.php on line 425
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() in
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/page.php:19
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-includes/template-loader.php(74):
>   include() #1
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-blog-header.php(19):
>   require_once('/home/careeing/...') #2
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/index.php(17):
>   require('/home/careeing/...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   /home/careeing/public_html/oldbookdepot.in/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/page.php
>   on line 19

Comment: Seen missing files. Had you ever check whether those files exist?

Comment: I think I might have found the issue. I was checking the file permission again and found that in each theme, the file permission for Function.php file is 0. I tried changing it to 644 but it completely crashed the website.